# SQL - How to find a set of records that does NOT include a certain column value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am working with healthcare claims data and I need assistance proving out a hypothesis.

I want to find all claims of a particular drug that were not billed with the appropriate diagnosis code.

So say I have Drug-X that can only be billed if there is a diagnosis code of H99 (in the below Claim 123 is valid because it has the right code), I want to find claims that were billed with Drug-X but did NOT have a diagnosis code of H99 at all.

Also, the ICD10 Code can be attached to any row for a service (or all services) of that claim

In the below example: I'd like to be able to return just the records where the Claimd ID is 321

| Claim ID | Person ID | Service | ICD10 Code |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 555 | Injection | H99 |
| 123 | 555 | Drug-X |  |
| 123 | 555 | Exam |  |
| 123 | 555 | Diagnosis |  |
| 321 | 556 | Injection | H88 |
| 321 | 556 | Drug-X |  |
| 321 | 556 | Exam |  |
| 321 | 556 | Diagnosis |  |

I have tried using some where in (select distinct Claim ID) and `Exists` functions but they don't seem to work.

Comment: hmm, what's wrong with just: select * from yourtable where where Service = 'Drug-X' and [ICD10 Code] <> 'H99'

Comment: because the ICD10 Code does not necessarily have to be attached to the drug row, it can be on any of the other rows. I'll edit my example to make that make more sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using `group by` and `having` clause, the condition is getting Claims having at least one *Drug-X* and none of *H99* Code :

```
select t.*
from mytable t
inner join (
  select Claim_ID
  from mytable
  group by Claim_ID
  having count(case when Service = 'Drug-X' then 1 end) > 0
         and count(case when ICD10_Code = 'H99' then 1 end) = 0 
) as s on s.Claim_ID = t.Claim_ID
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/bZEUbFS4)

Comment: Window functions might be more efficient though. And I think the compiler often transforms a self-join to a window function because of this.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably more efficient to do this using window functions, rather than a self-join.

```sql
select t.*
from (
    select *,
      count_DrugX = count(case when Service = 'Drug-X' then 1 end) over (partition by Claim_ID),
      count_H99   = count(case when ICD10_Code = 'H99' then 1 end) over (partition by Claim_ID)
    from mytable t
) t
where count_DrugX > 0
  and count_H99 = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that uses `exists`:

```
with yourData as (
    select *
    from (values
        ('123', '555', 'Injection', 'H99'),
        ('123', '555', 'Drug-X', NULL),
        ('123', '555', 'Exam',NULL),
        ('123', '555', 'Diagnosis', NULL),
        ('321', '556', 'Injection', 'H88'),
        ('321', '556', 'Drug-X', NULL),
        ('321', '556', 'Exam',  NULL),
        ('321', '556', 'Diagnosis',  NULL)
    ) as x(ClaimID, PersonID, [Service], [IDC10])
), badClaims as (
    select ClaimID
    from yourData
    where [Service] = 'Drug-X'
        and not exists (
            select *
            from yourData as t
            where yourData.ClaimID = t.ClaimID
                and IDC10 = 'H99'
        )
)
select *
from yourData
join badClaims
    on badClaims.ClaimID = yourData.ClaimID;
```

Breaking it down, the cte badClaims looks for line items that have Drug-X and no line item in the same claim has IDC10 = H99. Once such claims are found, we return all line items for that claim.